# Geany text editor commenting

Tags: comments, text-editor, geany

Is there a way to highlight a section of code to be commented out in one swoop using geany text editor?

Comment: Year 2023. Geany still fails do commenting right..

Answer (score 77):

Control-E to toggle commenting.

Comment: Why does geany use `#~` for comments in bash instead of just `#`?

Comment: @becko: In fact it inserts three characters `#~ `. The last one is a space. I think the reason is to allow Geany to detect its own comments to be able to remove them when uncommenting and not to touch comments created different ways.

Comment: @becko: You can turn that off under "Comment toggle marker" in Preferences (I prefer setting it to a single space).

Comment: @becko, it is in preferences -> editor -> functions. I want to have `# ` (with space) but this does not work. Leaving empty the input will result to `#` which is not the standard commenting.

Comment: In version 1.37.1, I don't understand why Geany has shortcuts displayed in the menus for just about everything except "commenting and un-commenting". This  control-E shotcut doesn't act the same as the `Edit > Format > Comment Line(s)` (which doesn't insert that `~`).

Answer (score 6):

Yes there is, you just have to highlight the code you want to comment then right-click, mouse over format and and click on "Comment Line(s)" to comment the lines. To uncomment,instead of selecting "Comment Line(s)" select "Uncomment Line(s)".

Answer (score 6):

Control + E

Edit default comment: Preferences > Editor > Features > Comment toggle marker